# registerElement('my-tag', {prototype: progo}) how to do this with customeElements.define

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component, custom-element

I have the following:

```
var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument; // importee
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function() {
  // get template in this doc. This is importDoc.
  var template = importDoc.querySelector('template');

  // import template into
  var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

  // create the shadow root element
  var root = this.createShadowRoot();
  root.appendChild(clone);
};

document.registerElement('my-tag', {prototype: proto});
```

This works. How do I do this with createElements.define(...)?

Comment: Not sure where you got any of this, none of it is correct (very outdated). If you are not using ES 6 classes per the spec there is an [adaptor shim](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/master/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js) in the polyfills suite. Also checkout [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) for what the correct syntax should look like for a custom element.

Answer (score 1):

Well it was pretty easy I had forgotten that the connectedCallback() should just be a method in the class:

```
 var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument; // importee
 var template = importDoc.querySelector('template');

 class MyTag extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback () {
    // import template into clone
    var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

    // create the shadow root element
    var root = this.createShadowRoot();
    root.appendChild(clone);
  }
};
```

I spent way too much time trying to figure out how to add the prototype when all I had to do was create the method. Oh well.